# Service Fabric reliable state and F# default GetHashCode issue

Tags: f#, azure-service-fabric, datacontractserializer

I having an issue when trying to update a SF stateful service after updating a child object of the service state. The upgrade fails to pass the 1st upgrade domain with a 'package activation' error. Digging around in the event viewer on the offending node gives the below exception:

> Errormsg=TStore.OnApplyAddAsync: Unexpected exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at xxx.DataChildObject.GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp)
>      at xxx.Data.GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp)
>      at xxx.Data.GetHashCode() in C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\xxx\xxx\xxx.Core\Domain.fs:line 17
>      at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.OnApplyAdd(TransactionBase txn, MetadataOperationData metadataOperationData, RedoUndoOperationData operationRedoUndo, Boolean isIdempotent, String applyType) Assert=System.Exception:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)

The change to the 'DataChildObject' was to add a new field that is a tuple of 2 doubles.

I understand that F# is automatically generating equality methods and these must be triggered during SF state and that due to datacontact serialisation these are null during the GetHashCode check.

I don't understand exactly when this check is being performed or why though?

As a test i tried overriding the GetHasCode method on my DataChildObject, but this didn't change the error i get when trying to upgrade my service.

```
 [<DataContract>]
type DataChildObject =
    class
        [<DataMember(IsRequired=false,Name="Value1")>] val mutable Value1 : float * float
        [<DataMember(IsRequired=false,Name="Value2")>] val mutable Value2 : float * float
        [<DataMember(IsRequired=false,Name="NewValue")>] val mutable NewValue : float * float
        new (v1,v2) = {Value1=v1;Value2=v2;NewValue=1.0,1.0}            

        override this.GetHashCode() =
                let value1 = if (box this.Value1 = null) then 1 else this.Value1.GetHashCode()
                let value2 = if (box this.Value2 = null)  then 1 else this.Value2.GetHashCode()
                let newValue = if (box this.NewValue = null)  then 1 else (this.NewValue).GetHashCode()
                value1+value2+newValue

    end
```

I expect these domain objects to change more in the near future so any help in understanding exact how to get past or avoid this issue is helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You could use F# record, but in general you should strongly avoid building custom `GetHashCode` based on values of mutable object. Imagine that you've added this to some set or as key in dictionary, and afterwards change the values - your collection will no longer be consistent and could cause random errors.

Comment: I don't see how your code chunk would compile. Are you sure you posted the exact code you have? Even if so, you're overriding the wrong method. According to the call stack, the crash happens in `GetHashCode` with one parameter.

Comment: Apologies the 'NewValue' member should not be commented out - edited

Comment: @Horusiath I agree with what you say - this was an experiment to see if i could find a way out of the situation i'm in. How will F# record solve this? I thought they would compile into a class with public get/set - same as the above class?

Comment: @AlexZevenbergen F# records are immutable. You just compose new value every time instead of mutating it `let newRecord = { oldRecord with SomeField = newValue }`

Comment: They are immutable in an F# context, but isn't that just compiler 'sugar'? I'd assume that when being deserialised Service Fabric would treat a record the same way as a class? [I have solved the above problem by storing my values separately in a dictionary instead of a concrete object, but would still like to understand how i could have 'fixed' my class above to allow me to safely add new members]